# Provide an example and explanation of an inner class in Java i need an real example where it going to use

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

please dont send link
please give me programming example where Inner class going to use and why we should use inner class

Comment: Although the question marked as duplicate doesn't necessarily fit, this answer to it seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/70687/1319284

Answer (score 0):

You can be more OOP by extracting some functionality out into its own class. Java GUI programming with Swing uses inner classes extensively, so you have the functionality separated out but still located together in the same place in the same class.